# Johnsons Criteria and Resolution

Tags: optics

I need to workout how many Pixels I need for my detector in an EO systems. But I am stuck in understanding what the Johnson Criteria is telling me:

I have the following equation from [Surveillance and Target Acquisition Systems](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Surveillance-Target-Acquisition-Systems-Rodgers/dp/185753137X):

\begin{array}{l}
\frac{R( m)}{H( m)} =\frac{f( mm)}{h( mm)}\\
\\
\\
\frac{NR( m)}{H( m)} =\frac{Nf( mm)}{h( mm)} =fk\\
\\
k=\frac{R}{Hf} N\\
\end{array}

Where k is the cycles per mm, R is the range, H is the target height, f is the focal distance

The Johnson Criteria says to Detect a target I need 1 Cycle, Recognition is 4 and Identification is 8.[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_criteria)

If I put in some values from the book: R = 1000m, H = 2 m, f = 100mm.

It tells me that that the height of the target on the detector will be ~10mm, so I need 5 pairs (5 cycles per mm).

It then goes on to multiple this 5 cy mm^-1 by the Johnson Criteria to get the required line pairs. So for Detection it states cycles needed is 5, for Recognition cycles needed is 20 and Identification cycles needed is 40

1. If my target is displayed over 5 pairs already. Why would I then multiple it by another 4 and need 20 pairs. Doesn't the Johnson criteria say that I only need 4 pairs to Identify it? What am I missing.
2. How, from these line pairs can I workout how many pixels my detector needs to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The height of the image on the detector will be Hf/R = 0.2 mm. In your equation k is 1/0.2 = 5/mm, which is the number of images that would fit in 1 mm. Multiply this by your Johnson Criteria to get the number of cycles per mm you need to be able to resolve. Further multiply by 2 to get the number of pixels per mm since you need two pixels to resolve a line/space pair. (The Nyquist criteria)

Comment: Thank you !!!!!